# I am getting an Invalid format for response in Github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-cli, amazon-sqs

I am trying to run an aws cli command in Github actions to get messages from a queue. I need to use the output from the queue in another job. According to aws cli document for queues [aws_receive_message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html) the format of the output is an object that returns a list of messages.

But i keep getting these errors from Github actions:

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.`
Error: Invalid format '    "Messages": ['
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
- name: Receive Message
  id: receive_message
  run: |
     message=`aws sqs receive-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-east1.amazonaws.com/myqueue.fifo \
     --attribute-names All \
     --message-attribute-names All --max-number-of-messages 10 --output json`
     echo result $message
     echo "message=$message" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

- name: Print Message
  id: print_message
  run: echo "${{ fromJson(steps.receive_message.outputs.message) }}"
```

I am assuming it something to do with the list being returned in the output that is not json formatted, but I am not sure how to resolve this.[image]

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this error?

Comment: Try: `echo "message=$(jq -c '. | @json' <<< "$message")" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"` and in the next step `echo '${{ toJson(fromJson(steps.receive_message.outputs.message)) }}'`.

Comment: This partially works. The first job runs fine, but the second job throws an error saying   command not found
`/home/runner/work/_temp/a5cac8a1-ac2a-412a-a8da-c5479bade74d.sh: line 1: b8493db4:0"}}]}: command not found`
`Error: Process completed with exit code 127.`

Comment: Second job or step? The workflow step in your question is "Print Message" but the error is from "Delete Message" step. However, both seems like similar. Anyways, always use single quotes around `${{...}}` i.e. `echo "${{ fromJson(steps.receive_message.outputs.message) }}"`. Also, you may need to use `toJson` also to print it with indentation. You should add the sample JSON in your question as text as well.